# Change the color of the icon by retaining the color inside

Tags: java, android

I have a location icon in red color with a white circle in it.
I want to change the color of it programmatically to yellow color retaining the white colored circle.
I am using this code -

```
Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_icon);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
drawable.draw(canvas);
return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

How do I theme it to yellow color by retaining the white circle inside it?

[image]

Comment: do you want to change all the white or just the circle in the middle ?

Comment: I want to change the red to yellow and retain white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get All the pixels and change one by one to the color you need.

Exemple:

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.yourRes);
myBitmap=immutableBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

int [] pixels = new int [myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];

myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());

for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
{
    if(pixels[i] == Color.RED)
    {
        pixels[i] = Color.YELLOW;
    }
}

myBitmap.setPixels(pixels,0,myBitmap.getWidth(),0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Tried but no luck :(

Comment: why you don't use another approach use 2 image one in red and one yellow and the trick is just to change between them ?

Comment: Just a question your image is JPEG or PNG ?, if it's JPEG try to use the same code with PNG format

Comment: it is a png... I dont want to use 2 different images because then I have so many resources for 1 image with different colors

Comment: Also try to check the real code of your color you want to change because I think it's not exactly red

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this specific icon you could use vector asset from google and change the tint color for it. Check the link below:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running